# SPI SBC communication

Tags: spi, freescale, sbc

I am using MPC5748G controller, in that i want to communicate my SPI with the SBC chip on board i.e MC33905, By going through the data sheet I am sending the proper commands to SBC through SPI API's for INIT WDG, INIT regd,... Please refer the attached file for the command set I have sent.
Now I have to observe the MISO line , what should be the response from SBC after we send each command we are not getting. Please help me understanding the response from SBC for each SPI commands. 
I have tried debugging it and catching the lines on Beagle SPI analyzer there i am receiving some data , but am not sure that data is correct or not, How can i read the mode of SBC this is the main task for us.

Please help me in this as this is high priority.

This is my code

```
volatile Spi_StatusType SpiStatus01;
 unsigned short int Init_WDG[1] = {0x4C10};   //  command to initialize WDG
 unsigned short int Init_Regd[1] = {0x4A00};  // Command to initialize registers
 unsigned short int Init_Misc[1] = {0x5000};  // Command for Misc initializations
 unsigned short int Init_WDG_Time[1] = {0x541F};  // command to initialize WDG time
 unsigned short int WDG_Refresh[1] = {0x5A00};    // command to refresh WDG
 unsigned short int Read1[1] = {0x2500};          // Command to read the status of SBC
 unsigned short int Read2[1] = {0x1F00};          // command to read the status of SBC
 unsigned short   tc_01[1],tc_02[1];              // Receive buffers


/*******************************************************************************
**                      Local Function Declarations                           **
*******************************************************************************/


/*******************************************************************************
**                         Function Definitions                               **
*******************************************************************************/

/*Init test case*/
void TC_Init()
{


uint8 i;
/*  Spi initialization */       
Spi_Init(&SpiDriver_0);

/*  Get the status of   Spi after   initialization */
 SpiStatus01 = Spi_GetStatus();

 Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,Init_WDG);   

Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);

Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,Init_Regd);

Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);

Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,Init_Misc);

Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);

Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,Init_WDG_Time);

Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);



   //module initialisation


 Can_Init(&CanConfigSet_0);

  // set the controller mode to START 
  Can_SetControllerMode(0,CAN_T_START);
  Can_SetControllerMode(1,CAN_T_START);

 while (1)
 {
 Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,WDG_Refresh);

Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);



 Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,Read1);
 Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);
 Spi_ReadIB (SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,tc_01);



Spi_WriteIB(SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,Read2);
 Spi_SyncTransmit(SpiConf_SpiSequence_SpiSequence_0);
         for(i=0; i<=100; i++);
 Spi_ReadIB (SpiConf_SpiChannel_SpiChannel_0,tc_02);

     for(i=0; i<=100; i++);

 /*Transmit test case  */
     Test_transmit(3,1,1);

 }      
}
```

Comment: For very specific questions such as this, you are probably better off asking the manufacturer directly. Freescale usually gives very good support, see [this page](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/homepage.jsp?code=SUPPORTHOME).

Comment: It sounds like you need a logic analyzer and oscilloscope!

Comment: @ConnorWolf: True, but the Beagle basically is a logic analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you select the correct sampling edge?
Data are valid on trailing clock edge.

Furthermore Spi_SyncTransmit is blocking function, so i guess there is no need to add a for-loop